# Quantum simulation for finding eigenfunctions of complicated Hamiltonians exactly

Tags: chemistry

Currently I am an undergrad in chemistry taking a quantum computing class and I'm looking for a topic for a small project involving literary review of QC articles. I was wondering if quantum computing can be used to solve for  exact solutions of wavefunctions. From a quantum/computational-chemistry point of view we often have to use approximation methods like the Hartree-Fock method  and then apply corrections to model physical behaviors. I was wondering if there is research on solving these complicated Hamiltonians exactly by harnessing the power of quantum computing.